# Unexpected error encountered :Could not find work item handler

Tags: jbpm

I created a custom workitem similar to the one [here](https://developer.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2013/12/29/jbpm6--custom-work-item-hello-process-example) and it works fine with eclipse when i run it. I deployed it and it deployed successfully, however when i try to start the process, I get this error

> Could not find work item handler for HelloProcessExtension

HelloProcessExtension is the name of my custom workitem

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your work item handler. If you use jBPM engine embedded in your application, you can do that by calling `registerWorkItemHandler(...)` method of `WorkItemManager` (which can be retrieved from [ProcessRuntime](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e1929)). Otherwise, if you use KIE Workbench or KIE Server, you can register it by adding it to [kie-deployment-descriptor.xml](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-server-parent/kie-server-tests/kie-server-integ-tests-all/src/test/filtered-resources/kjars-sources/definition-project/src/main/resources/META-INF/kie-deployment-descriptor.xml) in `META-INF` directory of your KJAR.

Comment: I am not sure where exactly I can find the kie-deployment-descriptor.xml, should i create one in the META-INF of my project before i deploy or is that already on the workbench and i should i add some line to it?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to achieve. If you want to use your work item handlers in all your projects, then you need to edit `kie-deployment-descriptor.xml` in the Workbench WAR file. This is global configuration which can be overwritten by the one in your project. You can either manually create this file in your project or configure work item handlers using GUI. You will find it somewhere in the project configuration.

Comment: I want to use the handler in all my projects. Could you please tell me where i should find the xml file so I can edit it. I cant find it on the workbench GUI

Comment: You can find it in `kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/kie-deployment-descriptor.xml`. In the workbench it is under Authoring -> Open Project Editor -> Project Settings -> Deployment descriptor -> Work item handlers.

Comment: In Workbench it is in Project Editor(Open Project Editor button in Project Explorer under Authoring->Project Authoring): then in drop down of Project Settings under Deployments - Deployment Descriptor

Answer (score 1):

Important note on this is that if you make the deployment with Workbench, you have to create the default Knowledge base, Knowledge session and add you Work Item Handler to it. This is the space where it execute. Probably in your case you do not have it and it can not find it.

In workbench Knowledge Base Settings are under Project Settings, in Knowledge bases and sessions.